# Unterschied zwischen "das Hühnchen" und "das Hähnchen"

Tags: word-usage, synonym

Was ist das Unterschied zwischen "das Hühnchen" und "das Hähnchen"? Ich habe oft in den Menus deutscher Restaurants das Wort "Hähnchen" gesehen, aber ich weiß  nicht, ob dieses Wort ein Synonym für "Hühnchen" ist oder nicht.

Ist es wahr, dass "Hühnchen" für weibliche Tiere benutzt wird und "Hähnchen" für die männlichen?

Das würde bedeuten, dass man in Deutschland meistens nur männliche Hühner isst!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Das Hühnchen* ist die [Diminutiv](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Diminutiv) -form von "das Huhn".

*Das Hähnchen* ist demnach zunächst einmal das Diminutiv zu "der Hahn". In der Gastronomie - zum Beispiel auf der Speisekarte - bezeichnet *das Hähnchen* aber lediglich ein Huhn, das für den Verzehr gemästet wurde. (Siehe auch hier: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haehnchen#Bedeutung2)

Offiziell bezeichnet *das Huhn* lediglich die Gattung und nicht das Geschlecht. Das männliche Huhn heißt *Hahn*, das weibliche *Henne*. Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch wird *Huhn* aber auch synonym für *Henne* verwendet. (Siehe [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Huhn), Bedeutung 1a und b.) Ebenso verhält es sich im gastronomischen Bereich mit *Hähnchen* und *Hühnchen*. Im Allgemeinen kann daraus kein Rückschluss auf das Geschlecht gezogen werden.

Answer (score 5):

Die Unterscheidung in der Bezeichnung stammt aus Zeiten, als *Hühnchen* zum großen Teil langjährige Legehühner waren, die nur geschlachtet wurden, weil sie nicht mehr genug Eier legten. Solche Hühner sind dann natürlich schon älter und ihr Fleisch ist nicht besonders zart – sie wanderten meist als Suppenhuhn in den Topf.

*Hähnchen* fanden i. Allg. keine Verwendung auf dem Bauernhof (ein Hühnerhof „funktioniert“ am besten mit einem einzigen Hahn …) und wurden daher wesentlich jünger (mit 1–2 Monaten) geschlachtet; ihr Fleisch ist deswegen zarter und besser zum Braten oder Grillen geeignet.

Und: Auch wenn *Hähnchen* draufsteht, darf (und ist tatsächlich) auch ein weibliches Huhn drin sein, es muss nur das Kriterium des maximalen Alters (ich glaube, max. 72 Tage) erfüllen. Die Deutschen essen also genauso viele männliche wie weibliche Hühner bzw. was halt grade so kommt.

Die Unterscheidung ist also in erster Linie ein Qualitätsmerkmal für das Fleisch und dürfte heute, da Hühner eben entweder „für den Topf“ oder „den Grill“ oder „zum Eierlegen“ jeweils speziell gezüchtet werden, nicht mehr besonders relevant sein. Die Tatsache, dass die Begriffsunterscheidung anscheinend das Geschlecht betrifft, ist heute (zumindest bei Hühnern) an sich nur noch historisch. *Hähnchen* bzw. *Brathähnchen* ist also primär die Bezeichnung für einen Kochrohstoff anstatt für ein männliches oder weibliches Tier.

Anders verhält es sich mit den männlichen Tieren anderer (i. Allg. kleiner) Vogelarten: Ein *Wellensittich-Hähnchen* ist immer ein männliches Tier.

Answer (score 0):

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geflügel#Hähnchen

> Hähnchen oder Broiler sind – anders als der Name nahelegt – Hühner beiderlei Geschlechts mit einem Gewicht von 800 bis 1200 g. Die in der heute üblichen Mast eingesetzten Masthybriden sind auf sehr hohe tägliche Zunahmen gezüchtet und erreichen ihr Schlachtgewicht bereits nach vier bis fünf Wochen; bei langsam wachsenden Rassen, die vor allem in der ökologischen Landwirtschaft eingesetzt werden, nach etwa sieben bis zehn Wochen. Schwerere und ältere Hähnchen werden auch Poularden oder Masthähnchen genannt.

Comment: "Broiler" war mir als deutscher Audruck für gebratenes Hähnchen noch nicht bekannt, außer im Englischen. Jetzt lese ich bei Wikipedia, dass man ausgerechnet in der westfeindlichen DDR das englische Wort benutzte und das es in Ostdeutschland immer noch gebraucht wird. Aber man müßte darauf hinweisen,  dass Broiler für Hähnchen im Deutschen kein allgemein verbreitetes Wort ist.

Comment: @rogermue: Zur regionalen Verwendung der unterschiedlichen Begriffe für Hähnchen gibt es hier eine schöne Grafik mit Erläuterungen: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/9_01b/ (wurde auch hier verwandt: http://www.zeit.de/feature/mauerfall-das-geteilte-land)

Comment: @Veredomon: Man sollte vielleicht noch dazu sagen, dass vermutlich die Mehrheit der Deutschen antworten würde, dass Hähnchen von Hahn käme und somit männlich sei (junges Fleisch für Brathähnchen) und Hühnchen von Huhn käme und weiblich sei (alte Legehenne als Suppenhuhn). Jetzt mal völlig offen gelassen, ob das früher mal gestimmt hat oder heute nur noch teilweise zutrifft.

Comment: Danke für die Sprachatlas-Karte zu den regionalen Varianten für Brathähnchen.Dass im Osten Broiler gebraucht wird hab ich zuvor noch nie gehört und ich frag mich, wieviele Deutsche das überhaupt nicht verstehen.

Comment: Etwas mehr als nur ein Link zu Wikipedia wäre wünschenswert.

Comment: @rogermue: Der Begriff "Broiler" wird in jeder Fernsehsendung zum Thema Osten/Westen erwähnt, also haben auch Wessies wie ich eine gute Chance, ihn zu kennen. Es gibt für viele Küchenbegriffe regionale Ausdrücke, und nicht nur im Osten/Westen, aber deshalb ist der jeweils unbekannte Ausdruck nicht falsch oder "allen anderen ungeläufig".

Comment: [Ist mir sofort zum Thema *Broiler* eingefallen](https://youtu.be/c0AMjiYs03g). CC @rogermue weil du oben stehst ;)